# Purpose of distribution "over" a variable notation

Tags: distributions, terminology, notation

The deep learning book (Goodfellow, Bengio, and Courville, 2016)'s [notation](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/notation.html) section says $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{x}; \mathbf{\mu}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$ represents a normal distribution over $\mathbf{x}$, which I thought was just a shorthand for specifying the dimensions or for referencing a distribution without needing to write $\mathbf{x} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{\mu}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$.

However, I see it used in the paper [Denoising Diffusion Probabilistic Models (Ho et al., 2020 at NeurIPS)](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2020/hash/4c5bcfec8584af0d967f1ab10179ca4b-Abstract.html) in the form
$$p_θ(x_{t−1}|x_t) := N (x_{t−1}; \mu_θ(x_t, t), \Sigma_θ(x_t, t))$$
where the dimensionality isn't in question, and the normal distribution isn't over the marginal $x_{t-1}$, rather the conditional $x_{t-1} \mid x_t$.

I'm wondering what the $x_{t-1}$ in the $N(x_{t-1}; ...)$ notation actually means.

Comment: Could you propose more than one reasonable interpretation of the notation in this context?  Please note that the very first sentence of section 2 in the paper establishes that the objects referenced by "$p_\theta$" are probability *densities.*  That would seem to leave only one natural way to interpret the right hand side: it must be a density, too.

Comment: I'm not questioning whether the RHS is a density, rather the meaning of "$x_{t-1}$" in $N(x_{t-1}; ...)$. I'll update the question to make that more clear.

Comment: The appearance of "$x_{t-1}$" on the right hand side is superfluous, but some authors seem to like to include it especially when they are using the "$\mathcal N$" notation to refer to a density function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that come across this, I finally understood it like this: $N(x; \mu, \sigma)$ denotes the PDF of $N(\mu, \sigma)$ **evaluated** at $x$.

It seems obvious now but for some reason I kept interpreting the $x$ as defining some part of the distribution rather than being the argument of the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

In that paper, $x_{t-1}$ the previous latent variable in the sequence. Eq. (1) specifies a factored distribution over the entire sequence: it's a Markov chain. They're modeling the backward direction in the chain: each element depends only on its successor.

In other words, they're modeling the answer to the question: "What's the state of the past ($x_{t-1}$), given the current state of the world ($x_t$)?"

Comment: I see that is what they are trying to convey, but why wouldn't they then write $N(x_{t-1} \mid x_t; \mu...)$? Because the distribution is not over $x_{t-1}$, but rather $x_{t-1} \mid x_{t}$.

Comment: There is no quantity $x_{t-1} \mid x_t$. This is a distribution over the variable $x_{t-1}$.

First, the authors first write it as $P(x_{t-1} \mid x_t)$, showing that they care about the [conditional [distribution over $\mathbf{x}_{t-1}$] given $\mathbf{x}_t$]. (I've put brackets to show how to parse it.)

Then, they specify exactly _how_ it depends on $x_t$: the parameters of the conditional distribution are functions of $\mathbf{x}_t$, as given: $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{x}_{t-1}; \mathbf{\mu}_\theta(\mathbf{x}_t, t), \Sigma_{\theta}(\mathbf{x}_t, t))$.

Comment: How do you figure there is no quantity $x_{t-1} \mid x_t$? It's called a conditional random variable, whereas $x_{t-1}$ on its own has been marginalized over all values of $x_t$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution) and [here](https://webspace.maths.qmul.ac.uk/r.a.bailey/MTH4106/notes15.pdf). If $P(x_{t-1} \mid x_t)$ is already assumed to be the quantity of interest why confuse things by introducing just $x_{t-1}$ into the normal distribution?

Comment: Then it seems you're clear on what a conditional distribution is; it makes it less clear to me what your question is. And in no way does the notation _confuse_ things by making them explicit. The authors are consistent in their notation. It's not clear what alternative you would propose that makes you more comfortable with the concept.

Comment: If you accept that "$x_{t-1}$" and "$x_{t-1}$ given some $x_t$" describe two different probability distributions, then using one when you mean the other I can only assume because takes less time to write is not only inconsistent with basic probability notation but unclear to someone trying to understand the concept. I was hoping someone could provide some insight on the choice of notation. If I saw $q(x \mid y) := N(x; f(y), \sigma)$ I would be confused as to why $x$ conditioned on $y$ is both defined as $x$ marginalized over $y$ and that it depends on $y$.

Comment: Nobody on this site will deny that conditional probability distributions exist. In no way is x being marginalized over y in what your most recent comment shows. You've not yet suggested an alternative notation; I can only guess your intent: would you prefer $q(x \mid y) := N(f(y), \sigma)$? Remember from the second link you provided that a conditional random variable depends on binding a particular value of the conditioning variable: $X \mid Y = y$.

Comment: The alternative notation would either be $N(f(y), \sigma)$ as you said or $N(x \mid y; f(y), \sigma)$. The idea being that if we are verbosely including an RV in the $N(...)$ notation, we should fully specify its distribution. When I see an RV $x$ on its own (in any context) as opposed to $(x \mid y)$, I assume it is a marginalized distribution, is this an unreasonable assumption?